# Are there any DBMS-specific SQL client Java libraries out there (not necessarily JDBC related nor compliant)

Tags: java, sql, mysql, sql-server, oracle

This is the scenario:

- I need to replace MySQL, Oracle and SQL Server sql clients with Java code
- I need to run sql script files with DBMS-specific statements from that Java code
- I've been searching and all I found was JDBC drivers for which you have to prepare statements and such.

So, to be more specific: are there any Java libraries that replace any of those DBMS clients? There's no need for it to be based on JDBC, I'd manage to call the proper library.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try SQL Squirrel.  I think it's a great looking client, written entirely in Swing.  You can use it as the client for any database that has a JDBC driver.

Comment: I'll have a thorough look at it. I don't really need the GUI part, but it seems like it can replace any DBMS specific client with a proper plug-in. Thanks!